# Single line comment macro chokes gcc

Tags: c, gcc, macros, comments

atest.c

```
#define COMMENT /##/

int main()
{
   ...
   COMMENT int atest;
   ...
}
```

The error messages:

`atest.c:16:1: error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token`

`atest.c: In function 'main':`

`atest.c:16: error: expected expression before '/' token`

While Microsoft C compiler is happy with the COMMENT macro. The tip of [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401344) doesn't work too.

Could someone give a solution or explanation for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

When you use the token pasting operator `##`, the result of combining the two operands must be a valid preprocessor token.

`//` is not a valid preprocessing token. Preprocessing happens after comments are removed so it is not possible to add comments at the preprocessing stage.

Answer (score 4):

Because comment processing is done *before* macros, so the comment generated by the macro is not recognized by the compiler. Quoting the response of Ben Combee on the article you referenced:

> I just read your C/C++ Tip #5, published in the January 2001 issue of
>   CUJ. The content of the tip (doing a macro that expands into a
>   comment) was quite familiar, since I'd seen a similar method deployed
>   in one of Microsoft's header files. However, the tip is very
>   incorrect.
>
> The writer uses token pasting to construct a comment start sequence.
>   However, this is invalid according to the C and C++ Standards. In
>   section 5.1.1.2 of ISO C (1999), titled "Translation phases," comment
>   processing occurs in phase 3 where the preprocessor identifies tokens
>   and whitespace, with comments replaced with whitespace. Macro
>   processing is then done in phase 4, and that phase is the one in which
>   these new comment start sequences would be introduced. There is no
>   followup phase after #4 where the comment would be recognized, so
>   eventually a conforming compiler would reject the program text due to
>   an illegal token — '//'. The 1998 C++ Standard has similar language in
>   section 2.1, "Phases of translation [lex.phases]."
>
> Some compilers mix the order and processing of phases sufficiently to
>   allow this macro to work, Microsoft's Visual C++ 6.0 being notable for
>   its popularity. Others, such as the Metrowerks CodeWarrior C/C++
>   compilers (upon which I worked for over two years as a compiler
>   engineer before my current employment) follow the Standard and will
>   reject the usage shown in the tip.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Ben Combee
>   Lead Software Architect
>   Veriprise Wireless
>   http://www.veriprise.com

Accordingly, the journal followed by this notice:

> **We therefore want to caution readers that this tip is not portable and probably should not be used in production code.**

Comment: Thank you all for the explanations. Actually, this question came from a situation when I ran splint on my project and splint failed on a line similar to the COMMENT. Then I wrote atest.c and tested the COMMENT on the gcc. However, what surprised me was that when I ran splint on the above atest.c, splint was happy and gave message "atest.c(16,13): Variable atest declared but not used".

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I don't have the answer on how to do this.

You can use the command cpp (the c prepocessor) to preprocess your code and see what is happening.
Running your provided code through cpp gives the following:

```
int main()
{
a.c:5:1: error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
       / / int atest;
}
```

Trying

```
#define COMMENT /
#define SLASH(x) x/

SLASH(COMMENT)
```

results in

```
/ /
```

However trying

```
#define TEST(y) y/
TEST(hello)
```

results in

```
hello/
```

Usually comments such as // are stripped out and replaced with a single 'comment token', this step is done before preprocessing (when # directives take place) and thus even if you could get your comment in there, I doubt it would always be recognised (AFAIK the standard doesn't guarantee it).

I'm sorry I can't be more help.